# Unprivileged access to GAE Memcache?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, memcached

Is there way to access someones Memcache in Google App Engine? 
Any docs about Memcache security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All GAE services, including memcache, are per-application. This is enforced at API level, there is no (known) way to access services in the name of some other app.